# Python inconsistently importing

Tags: python, import

I have two different scripts with identical import statements that are similar to this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:/pathname/ImportFile')
import ImportFile as impFile
```

In my first script, this works just fine.

In my second script, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named ImportFile
```

Exactly the same statements, mind you. Why??

Comment: `ImportFile.__file__` is?

Comment: This searches for a module "c:/pathname/ImportFile/ImportFile.py"  or a package (directory) "c:/pathname/ImportFile/ImportFile".

Comment: `sys.path.append(r'c:\pathname')`?

Comment: @CristiFati, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I do not understand. The exact same code works fine on one script but fails on the other.

Comment: Do both scripts only contain this code (especially do they contain something before it)? Are both the main script or are they imported as modules from other code? Are both in the same directory?

Comment: I took a wild guess. What is `ImportFile`? Where are the 2 scripts located? Could you share them? Are you executing them from the same spot (e.g. console?). In these situations, it's better to make use of every resource available: print in both (**before** the *mighty import*): `sys.path`, `os.environ`, `sys.executable`, `os.getcwd()` **<-**, `sys.version_info` :), and check any differences between those items.